# What is the Most Ideal Way to Await a Set of Tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asynchronous, async-await

I am exploring `async`/`await` and have found a curious scenario that I need guidance on resolving.

For reference, the code seen in this question can be found here:

https://github.com/Mike-EEE/Stash/tree/master/AwaitPerformance

I have provided two simple ways of awaiting a set of tasks.  The first is simply creating a `List<Task>`, adding tasks to this list, and awaiting the entire result at once with a call to `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task<uint> AwaitList()
{
    var list = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0u; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Task.Delay(1));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(list).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return 123;
}
```

The second is by awaiting each task as they occur in the `for` loop:

```
public async Task<uint> AwaitEach()
{
    for (var i = 0u; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return 123;
}
```

When running these two methods with Benchmark.NET, however, I get surprisingly conflicting results:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X, 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100-preview5-011568
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 (CoreCLR 4.6.27622.75, CoreFX 4.700.19.22408), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 (CoreCLR 4.6.27622.75, CoreFX 4.700.19.22408), 64bit RyuJIT


|    Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| AwaitList |  15.60 ms | 0.0274 ms | 0.0243 ms |     - |     - |     - |    2416 B |
| AwaitEach | 155.62 ms | 0.9113 ms | 0.8524 ms |     - |     - |     - |     352 B |
```

As you can see, awaiting the list of tasks is much faster, but generates a ton of allocations.  Awaiting each item, however, is the inverse: it is slower but generates way less garbage.

Is there an obvious, ideal way that I am overlooking to get the both of best worlds here?  That is, is there a way to await a set of `Task` elements that is both fast and results in a low amount of allocations?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What do those results look like when you delay longer, perhaps 50ms or 100ms? 1ms is odd because it doesn't resemble most things we would do asynchronously.

Comment: The `WhenAll` approach is basically allowing the tasks to run in parallel.  The other approach will not start the next task until the previous one is complete.  Which approach you use is based on what the tasks do.  If they are related and need to be done in sequence then you have to do the second approach.  If not, you can opt for the first.

Comment: +1 for the both of you... thank you!  I started to increase the delay time as @ScottHannen suggested and realized that there were two separate effects occurring as @juharr mentions.  Knowing this, it would seem that the `AwaitEach` is clearly the winner as it is not only abiding by the time delay but also has way less allocations.  Hopefully this will help out another async/await newb like me out there.

Comment: No, AwaitEach is not clearly the winner as like juharr mentioned each task runs sequentially, whereas in AwaitList they run in parallel. So if you have five tasks each taking a minute to complete AwaitEach would take 5 minutes, but AwaitList would complete after only 1 minute. The small overhead of a few kilobytes is negligible in comparison.

Comment: To evaluate the memory vs time effectiveness one would multiply the two units together (you can picture it like man-hrs). So AwaitList `(15.60ms * 2416B) = 37689.6` and AwaitEach `(155.62ms * 352B) = 54778.24` Now our unit on each of those scores is the amount of memory-time consumed, less is more efficient. So you can easily see that AwaitList is way more efficient in terms of the amount of memory consumed for a given length of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are not comparing apples to apples here.**

In your example:

- AwaitList creates a list of Tasks and then runs them all parallel (async).
- AwaitEach runs each Task one after another hence making the async keyword useless.

---

If, however, you make your list of Tasks, so that each task can start and then compare WhenAll vs a loop, your comparison would look like this:

```
public async Task<uint> AwaitList()
{
    var list = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0u; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Task.Delay(1));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(list).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return 123;
}
```

verses

```
public async Task<uint> AwaitEach()
{
    var list = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Task.Delay(1));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await list[i].ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return 123;
}
```

Now compare the stats on these two functions and you will find they are ballpark of one another.

Comment: Ahhh I can't even with myself after this question.  I was tempted to delete it once I learned my misunderstanding yesterday and now I have two downvotes along with an answer with four upvotes. Gutpunch.  I AM NOT VERY GOOD AT THIS.   I should have simply deleted it and am tempted to do so now, but I will eat my turdsammich and allow my pain to be your gain @Rhaokiel.  Nice work with this. 